# Add new iOS Distribution Certificate without revoking the existing certific

Tags: ios, xcode, ad-hoc-distribution, in-house-distribution

My distribution certificate is going to expire soon so, I have created a new distribution certificate. So, I just want to know that how do I add the new distribution certificate without revoking the existing one.

Thanks

Comment: After creating the new distribution certificate , from iTunesConnect you have to go in the ProvisioningProfile section. In this section you should see your distribution provisioning profile. Select the profile. You should have the possibility to define which distribution certificate to use.